# I'm getting an error when testing the model of my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm currently doing tests in my model.
I put .bak on all of yml files in fixtures.

I have this validation:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :tasks

validates :categoryname,presence:true,length:{minimum:5}
validates :categorybody,presence:true,length:{minimum:5}
validates :user_id,presence:true
end
```

This is my test:

```
require "test_helper"

class CategoryTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

test "should save if category name is more than 4 letters" do
category = Category.new(categoryname: "testing")
assert category.save
end
```

It met the validations but M'm getting this error:

```
Failure:
CategoryTest#test_should_save_if_category_name_is_more_than_4_letters 
[/home/azarlorea/journalz/journalv/test/models/category_test.rb:27]:
Expected false to be truthy.
```

I created a new Rails app with the same code except that I removed the associations and the user id validation and it is working fine there.

Thanks

Comment: You could add a debug point before `assert category.save` and try saving the `category` and as it is returning `false` you could check the `errors` there which would help in identifying the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, `category` cannot be saved as there are validation errors.

Even if you are checking for the `categoryname` you need to ensure you have other mandatory fields assigned.

You may try to test it something like this

```
test "should save only if category name is more than 4 letters" do
  user = User.create(mandatory params here...)
  category = Category.new(categoryname: "test", categorybody: "testing", user: user)
  assert_not category.valid?

  category.categoryname = "validname"
  assert category.valid?
end
```

Comment: Hi @Deepak Mahakale . I tried the code but it gives me the same error . Thank you for the info that i still need to add other params even i just want to test the categoryname

Comment: You will need to debug it. Try the same in `rails console`. check if you can create a category with the above fields or if there are any other validations

Comment: Its working . im sorry . Im just using category.save that is why im getting error . im trying to think about your code . its very helpful